# In KDE Plasma, how can I switch between virtual desktops using Meta + Tab?

Tags: shortcut-keys, plasma, plasma-5, virtualdesktop

I'm using KDE Plasma 5 right now, and I noticed that the keyboard shortcut Meta + Tab is used to switch between Activities, and Alt + Tab is obviously used to switch between windows. I would like to know if there's a similar way to switch between virtual desktops, and if so, how I can set Meta + Tab to toggle it. I only have two virtual desktops, each with a bunch of specifically positioned windows in them. I'd like something more efficient than clicking on the Pager widget every time I want to quickly switch. I'm a bit new at this, so I apologize if I'm obviously doing something wrong. Thanks, community!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The default shortcut for changing the desktop on KDE is <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F4</kbd>.

<kbd>meta</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> will show the grid view.

To change this, you can go to "System Settings" >> "Workspace" >> "Shortcuts" >> "Plasma" and here you can remap "Walk through activities" to something else or disable it

[image: Image of Plasma keyboard settings]

Now you can go to the search bar, type "desktop" and choose "Kwin" from the applications list. On the right you should see a list of shortcuts related to desktop switching. if I was you with just two desktops I would choose the "Switch to next desktop" shortcut, click it, and choose add a custom shortcut, don't forget to apply.

[image: Image of KWin keyboard settings]

That is it, there are a lot of shortcuts on KDE and it looks quite daunting but  is not too bad once you get it down.

Comment: Thanks for this! This is perfect, simple screenshots and everything! Finding the "switch to next desktop" shortcut was all I needed to replace Meta + Tab to simply toggle between my two desktops. Thanks again!

Comment: CONTROL+F8 doesn't open any grid view here

Comment: I figured it out, it's META+F8 for the grid view

Comment: In German, it's **Einstellungen** ➤ **Kurzbefehle** ➤ **Umschaltung der Tastaturbelegung** ➤ Then **search** for `kwin` ➤ **Arbeitsflächen-Raster anzeigen**. Bingo!

Answer (score 5):

Other way to change the virtual desktop than with a keyboard shortcut:

**Hover you mouse over desktop (no window can be covering the wallpaper in that spot) and use scroll.**

I am aware that this is not really an answer to this question, but I don't really see a better place to share this trick.

When I google "how to change desktops in KDE" this is the first result, and  others aren't really more appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

You can use KDE Overview. The default shortcut is <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> (Meta is usually windows key)

You can reassign the shortcut to <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.
This is similar to gnome's overview. The advantage of Overview is that you can create virtual desktops on the fly and also easily move applications between virtual desktops.

Note: It needs to be enabled. Go to Desktop Effects and Enable it. It needs compositor to be enabled (which will be by default)

Answer (score 3):

I have a additional comment to Mark Kirbys answer but unfortunately I'm not allowed to comment...

After applying Mark Kirbys answer I was not able to cycle through my desktops. When I arrived at my third and last desktop I was not able to go back to desktop 1 by pressing "meta + tab".

In order to enable this behaviour I needed to to the following: System Settings -> Workspace Behaviour -> Virtual Desktops -> enable "Navigation wraps around" at the bottom. Also shown in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNBnw.png) Picture. (I'm also not allowed to paste pictures...)

Comment: Ah, good tip. Thanks!